# How do I add properties to a "new" instance?

Tags: javascript, oop

How do I add properties to an instance of a `new function`?

For example:

```
function Constructor() {
    this.color = "red";
}

var s = new Constructor() {
    this.color = "blue";
    this.height = 30px;
}
```

When `s.height` is invoked, I am getting an undefined result. How does one execute this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Constructor() {
   this.color = "red";
}

var s = new Constructor();
s.color = "blue";
s.height = 30px;
```

Comment: @Andrew--do i have to put this into object literal syntax?

i.e. `var s = {color:"blue", height:30px)`

Comment: @codeninja No, that syntax will just create a new object with those properties, If you want to extend your Constructor object you must assign the properties like I have shown or like how ilia has done it.

Answer (score 3):

That's a syntax error. The `new Constructor()` call shouldn't be followed by braces, and the new instance should be referenced directly. also, the constructor definition needs the `function` keyword

```
function Constructor() {
  this.color = "red";
}

var s = new Constructor() 

s.color = "blue";
s.height = 30px;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function Constructor(options){
    for(var key in options){
        this[key] = options[key];
    }
}

var s = new Constuctor({color: "red",height: "30px"});
```

or

```
function Constructor(color,height){
    this.color = color;
    this.height = height;
}

var s = new Constuctor("red","30px");
```

Comment: @ilia_choly--could you explain the first example a little more? what is `key`?

Comment: @codeninja `{color: "red",height: "30px"}` is an [Object literal](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php)
the [for in loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) is looping through the properties of the object.

Comment: @Utilitron--does the `new` instance of `Constructor()` carry the same loop?

Comment: @codeninja you can think of it as being in the constructor. It runs when you create a new instance of the object.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are trying to do.

If in your example `s` is the only instance of `Constructor` that will have the property `height`, then do it like this:

```
function Constructor() {
  this.color = "red";
}

var s = new Constructor() 
s.height = 30px;
```

if you want to add the height property to all instances of `Constructor` then do it like this:

```
function Constructor() {
  this.color = "red";
}

Constructor.prototype.height = 30px;

var s = new Constructor();
```

if you want a new `Constructor` with height to be able to be instantiated then do it like this:

```
function Constructor() {
  this.color = "red";
}

function ConstuctorWithHeight(){
  this.height = 30px;
}

ConstuctorWithHeight.prototype = new Constructor();

var s = new ConstuctorWithHeight();
```